# Mock a public property on a static method?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking

I am using `Confide` which requires you do something like

```
Confide::user()->id
```

To get the *user ID*. And I am trying to mock this so it returns a garbage user id. I can mock `Confide::user()` fine by using *Laravel*'s built in *Facade* mocking

```
Confide::shouldReceive('user')->once()->andReturn('blah');
```

If I run `Confide::user()` it returns `blah`.

But how can I add a property so if I run `Confide::user()->id` it returns a mock value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
Confide::shouldReceive('user')->once()->andReturn( (object)array('id' => 42) );
```

That way you create an instance of `stdClass` with a single attribute `id = 42`.

Comment: +_+ apparently I've been staring at this too long.